# Prove that a function is not continuously differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:

$f(x,y)=
\ \begin{cases} 
      (x^2 + y^2)\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
       \\0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
   \end{cases}
\\$

Now, I am asked to prove that this function is not continuously differentiable at $(0,0)$, but it is differentiable on $R^2$. I have proven that it is differentiable by taking the first order partial derivatives, using the precise definition. It turns out that:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} at (0,0) = 0$

and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} at (0,0) = 0$

My question is how to proceed from here and prove that this function is not twice differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Question about the same function: [Proving a scalar function is differentiable at the origin but that its partial derivatives are not continuous at that point.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/607104). Found [using Approch0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2)%5Ccdot%20%5Csin(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%7D%7D)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0):

You have only shown that $f$ is partially differentiable at $(0,0)$ ! To show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ you have to show that

$\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-xf_x(0,0)-yf_y(0,0)}{||(x,y)||} \to 0$ for $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Try a proof !

Then you have to show that $f$ is not continuously differentiable at $(0,0)$.

To this end show that the partial derivative $f_x$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$

Comment: I have shown that it is differentiable at $(0,0)$, I just did not write it here, because the solution is long. So, it is enough to take the first-order partial derivative of f (not the one at $(0,0)$) and to show that it is not cont. at $(0,0)$? Because as I have shown the other one  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} at (0,0) = 0$.